# preg_replace in array php

Tags: php, mysqli, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

```
$search = array("<?php", "god", "gOd"); //do not want to do this in so many words\\
$replace = array("<-php", "God", "God");
$comment = str_replace($search, $replace, mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['comment']));
```

I want to include uppercase and lowercase letters in the array, how to do this for `$search` and `$replace`?

Comment: RTM use: [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

Comment: Thank you <3 you will not post your answer for me to vote as the best?

Comment: I won't post an answer for this one. Since it could been avoided with simple googl'ing

Comment: Improved formatting and removed irrelevant and confusing parts from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use regular expressions, write your code like this:

```
preg_replace('/regular expression here/i', 'replacement here', $string);
```

Otherwise use `str_ireplace()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root');
$a = array("<?php", "god", "gOd");
foreach ($a as &$v) {
    $v = mysqli_real_escape_string(
        $db,
        preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?!]/", '', $v)
    );
}
var_export($a);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => '?php',
  1 => 'god',
  2 => 'gOd',
)
```